# What's a quick way to simulate the shake gesture on Xcode 7's new UI automation?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, automation, ui-automation

Just looking for an easy/quick way to simulate the device shake gesture for UI automation. My script needs to simulate shaking to access some developer settings.

Comment: Have you tried starting the recorder and then doing the shake in the Simulator to see what code it inserts? (I can't now, so I don't know if this works)

Comment: Yeah... seems to not record anything 'outside' the main view. Recording doesn't pick up anything.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just directly call the function of yours that triggers on shake (i.e. whatever you're calling in `motionEnded:withEvent:`)?